# Do we really need a tag for "staff-weapon"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) tag - [weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) - for all weaponry - swords, axes, bows and arrows, missiles, guns, bombs, lasers, grenades, blasters, positronic antimatter discombobulators with dual metastasized particle flanges diverted through a network of supercooled serial uptake integrators, light sabers, pointy sticks, etc - and one for "staff-weapon".  As there is, to date, a [single](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/staff-weapon) question tagged [staff-weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/staff-weapon), can we get rid of it?

Comment: Like I care. Knock yourself out. Preferably not with a [tag:Staff-weapon], obviously.

Comment: Now I'm curious about the question, but the tag-based links don't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the tag is essentially worthless. Since it's been deleted by one of the site's high-rep users (an especially handsome one, I might add), you should see it disappear [within the next 24 hours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) unless someone tags it onto something else.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251221/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags